# Deleting a "Like" using Ajax throws Internal Server Error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internal-server-error

I'm somewhat new to how has_many trough relations and AJAX in Rails, I'm trying to make a simple "Like" system, where an user can like an event and "unlike" it, It works perfectly when an user likes an event, the change is saved to the database and the count refreshes no problem, however, when I try to delete the like, it throws me an Internal Server Error, further deletions throw a Not Found error, meaning the Like was deleted, but the count and button do not refresh until I refresh the whole page. This only happens when I try to use AJAX.

This is the destroy method:

```
def destroy
    @event = Like.find(params[:id]).event_id
    @evento = Event.find(@event)
    current_user.unlike(@event)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @evento }
      format.js
    end
end
```

The Button:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.find_by(event_id: @event.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unlike", class: "unlike_button" %>
<% end %>
```

and the JS:

```
$("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('events/like')) %>");
$("#likes").html('<%= @event.likes.count %>');
```

I could stop using AJAX, but I want to know what the problem is, and nothing I've found so far has solved the issue.

**Edit:**

Here are my models

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :events

  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_events, through: :likes, source: :event

  def like(event)
    liked_events << event
  end

  def unlike(event)
    liked_events.delete(event)
  end

  def likes?(event)
    liked_events.include?(event)
  end

end
```

The Like model:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :event_id, presence: true
end
```

and the Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes

end
```

**2nd Edit**

NoMethodError in Likes#destroy

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/events/_like.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `id' for 1:Fixnum
Did you mean?  i
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/likes/destroy.js.erb
Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

I've found this error thanks to the Chrome dev tools, still I'm not sure what to do to resolve the issue, I moved some variables around, mainly the one mentioned on the error, but to no avail.

Comment: Check the server log to see what the error is.

Comment: You should post your model code and your ajax call.

Comment: How can I check my server log?

I believe the ajax call is already there, since I'm using rails, it calls it in automatically, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you post the full error and the server log generated.